# Custom fields not always displaying on profile

Tags: custom-fields, profile

I'm having an intermitent issue with custom fields on a profile. Sometimes they are displaying fully and correctly, sometimes not (though name and email continues to be visible).
It seems if I go into the profile and change a setting (any setting for any field) it then starts to display properly again on the public profile.
Does anyone know why this is happening? We are on Drupal, on CiviCRM 5.58.1.

TIA

Comment: Are there any errors logged?

Comment: Also, does this happen in every context (previewing the profile, using the profile in create mode, using the profile in a contribution or even page)?

Comment: are you testing with different users? does Anonymous have the permission for 'access all custom fields' (or similarly named permission)

Comment: I think this may be https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2920.  Take a look at the replication steps there.  Do you have a role without the "CiviCRM: access all custom data" permission?  Try clearing cache and visit the profile immediately with an admin. Then clear cache and visit immediately with a user without "access all custom data".  If that controls whether the fields show up, it's the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the replies. That "custom data" permission wasn't set (but it did work sometimes without that being tagged, for non-logged-in users, so I'm not sure if that itself was the problem?) But I've ticked that now, and I've refreshed the caches, and that made it work for administrators and anonymous users. I'll keep an eye on it to see if it continues to work.
Thanks!